# UITableView sleeps when called from NSOperation

Tags: iphone, timeout, uitableview, nsoperation

I´m writing an app which needs to get its content from a website whenever the user taps a reload button.

If he does so an NSOperation is registered and put to NSOperationQueue.

When the NSOperation is starting (START QUEUE) it checks its cache and reloads the data from the server (CALL IMPORT1).
After this task the operation sends an Notification to my UITableView which queries the database (START READING / END READING) and then calls `[self.tableView reloadData];` (RELOAD DATA START)
Until here everything works as expected. Even if i import about 1.000 elements.

The thing that drives my crazy is that there´s some kind of sleep between "END QUEUE" and getting the first cell (CREATE CELL START). After this sleep the cells are created as they should be - very fast.

I can´t figure out what invokes this "sleep".

Can anybody please give me an hint what´s going wrong.

Thanks in advance Boris

**Called within viewDidAppear**

> 2011-01-29 15:54:34.460 [30488:207]
>   START READING   2011-01-29
>   15:54:34.461 [30488:207] END READING
>   2011-01-29 15:54:34.464 [30488:207]
>   RELOAD DATA START   2011-01-29
>   15:54:34.468 [30488:207] GET SECTIONS 
>   2011-01-29 15:54:34.469 [30488:207]
>   GET HEADER   2011-01-29 15:54:34.470
>   [30488:207] GET HEADER   2011-01-29
>   15:54:34.470 [30488:207] GET ROWS
>   2011-01-29 15:54:34.471 [30488:207]
>   CREATE CELL START   2011-01-29
>   15:54:34.473 [30488:207] CREATE CELL
>   STOP   2011-01-29 15:54:34.474
>   [30488:207] CREATE CELL START
>   2011-01-29 15:54:34.475 [30488:207]
>   CREATE CELL STOP   2011-01-29
>   15:54:34.476 [30488:207] CREATE CELL
>   START   2011-01-29 15:54:34.477
>   [30488:207] CREATE CELL STOP
>   2011-01-29 15:54:34.477 [30488:207]
>   GET HEADER

**Called via Notification** (The bold parts are new because of the NSOperation)

> **2011-01-29 15:54:04.719 [30488:630b] START QUEUE   2011-01-29 15:54:05.727
>   [30488:630b] CALL IMPORT1 START
>
>   2011-01-29 15:54:05.750 [30488:630b]
>   CALL IMPORT1 STOP   2011-01-29
>   15:54:05.760 [30488:630b] CALL VIEW
>   START**   2011-01-29 15:54:05.767
>   [30488:630b] START READING
>   2011-01-29 15:54:05.771 [30488:630b]
>   END READING   2011-01-29 15:54:05.781
>   [30488:630b] RELOAD DATA START
>   2011-01-29 15:54:05.786 [30488:630b]
>   GET SECTIONS   2011-01-29 15:54:05.791
>   [30488:630b] GET HEADER   2011-01-29
>   15:54:05.797 [30488:630b] GET HEADER
>   2011-01-29 15:54:05.802 [30488:630b]
>   GET ROWS
>   **2011-01-29 15:54:05.806 [30488:630b] CALL VIEW STOP   2011-01-29
>   15:54:05.811 [30488:630b] END QUEUE** 
>   2011-01-29 15:54:10.770 [30488:630b]
>   CREATE CELL START   2011-01-29
>   15:54:10.776 [30488:630b] CREATE CELL
>   STOP   2011-01-29 15:54:10.777
>   [30488:630b] CREATE CELL START
>   2011-01-29 15:54:10.778 [30488:630b]
>   CREATE CELL STOP   2011-01-29
>   15:54:10.778 [30488:630b] CREATE CELL
>   START   2011-01-29 15:54:10.780
>   [30488:630b] CREATE CELL STOP
>   2011-01-29 15:54:10.781 [30488:630b]
>   GET HEADER

Comment: Found the solution... the NSOperation sends the NSNotification on the secondary thread to my UITableViewController - this causes the delay. I found the solution on this site: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/08/safe-threaded-design-and-inter-thread.html  Hope this my help somebody!

Comment: If you found the solution, could you post it as an answer and then accept that answer?  That will stop this question from appearing as "unanswered".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution... the NSOperation sends the NSNotification on the secondary thread to my UITableViewController - this causes the delay.

I found the solution on this site: 
http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/08/safe-threaded-design-and-inter-thread.html

Hope this my help somebody!